# How do I keep my values the same each time I go around the while loop?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, project

I am making a two-person dice game where there are five rounds, but I want to keep the scores the same from the previous rounds, how do I do that?

The rules of the game are as follows:

• The points rolled on each player’s dice are added to their score.
• If the total is an even number, an additional 10 points are added to their score.
• If the total is an odd number, 5 points are subtracted from their score.
• If they roll a double, they get to roll one extra die and get the number of points rolled added to
their score.
• The score of a player cannot go below 0 at any point.
• The person with the highest score at the end of the 5 rounds wins.
• If both players have the same score at the end of the 5 rounds, they each roll 1 die and
whoever gets the highest score wins (this repeats until someone wins).

```
import random
import time


total_player2score = 0
total_player1score = 0
rounds = 0
player_1 = 0
player_2 = 0
while rounds != 5:
    total_player2score = total_player2score + player_2
    total_player1score = total_player1score + player_1
    rounds = rounds + 1
    number = random.randint(1, 6)
    number2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    total_player1score = number + number2
    print("*"*50)
    print("Round {}!".format(rounds))
    print("*"*50)
    print("Player 1's turn. Type 'roll' to roll the dice.")
    player1_input = input(">>> ")
    if player1_input == "roll":
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("Player 1's first roll is", number)
    print("Player 1's second roll.Type 'roll' to roll the dice")
    player1_input = input(">>> ")
    if player1_input == "roll":
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("player 1's second roll is", number2)
    if total_player1score % 2 == 0:
        total_player1score = total_player1score + 10
        print("Player 1's total is even so 10 points will be added")
        print("*"*50)
        print("Player 1 has", total_player1score, "points")
    else:
        total_player1score = total_player1score - 5
        total_player1score = max(0, total_player2score)
        print("player 1's total is odd so 5 points will be deducted")
        print("*"*50)
        print("Player 1 has", total_player1score, "points")
    number = random.randint(1, 6)
    number2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    total_player2score = number + number2
    print("*"*50)
    print("Player 2's turn. Type 'roll' to roll the dice")
    player2_input = input(">>> ")
    if player2_input == "roll":
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("Player 2's first roll is", number)
    print("Player 2's second roll.Type 'roll' to roll the dice")
    player2_input = input(">>> ")
    if player2_input == "roll":
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("player 2's second roll is", number2)
    if total_player2score % 2 == 0:
        total_player2score = total_player2score + 10
        print("Player 2's total is even so 10 points will be added")
        print("*"*50)
        print("Player 2 has", total_player2score, "points")
    else:
        total_player2score = total_player2score - 5
        total_player2score = max(0, total_player2score)
        print("player 2's total is odd so 5 points will be deducted")
        print("*"*50)
        print("Player 2 has", total_player2score, "points")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question could be improved if you reduced your code to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Currently it's hard to pinpoint the place in code that your question applies.

Comment: I don’t know where to actually improve my code so I can store values from previous rounds, so I put in everything so people viewing this question can know where my mistake is as well as know the point of the program.

Comment: you could store the scores in a .txt file like @herbaltea suggested below or you could create a dictionary for each player and set each key to the round and the value to the score.

Answer (score 1):

```
def writeUp(score_1,score_2,nameoffile):
    with open(f"{nameoffile}.txt","a") as logz:
        print(f"score1 {score_1}\nscore2 {score_2}",file=logz)



def readUp(nameoffile):
    with open(f"{nameoffile}.txt","r") as data:
        lines = data.readlines()
        last_2 = lines[:2]
        score_1,score_2 = None,None
        for element in last_2:
            splitt = element.split(' ')
            if element.find('score1') != -1:
                score_1 = int(splitt[1])
            elif element.find('score2') != -1:

                score_2 = int(splitt[1])

    return score_1,score_2



sci1,sci2 = 50,50
writeUp(sci1,sci2,'mysaves')

sc1,sc2 = readUp('mysaves')
print(sc1,sc2)
```

#this should help, the function given creates a txt file and store scores into it